# Continuous fields of Hilbert spaces arising from representations of abelian C*-algebras

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

This is a followup to a previous question [1] on MO.

Let $X$ be a second-countable, locally compact, Hausdorff space, and let $\mathscr H =\{H_x\}_{x\in X}$, be a
measurable field of Hilbert spaces over $X$.

Let us then say that $\mathscr H$ is *continuous* if it admits a compatible structure as a continuous
field of Hilbert spaces.  In concrete terms this amounts to the existence of a linear space $\mathscr S$
of measurable sections of $\mathscr H$, such that:

1. $\mathscr S$ is pointwise dense, namely
   $\mathscr S(x) := \{\xi (x): \xi \in  \mathscr S\}$
   is dense in $H_x$, for every $x$ in $X$.
2. for every $\xi $ and $\eta $ in $\mathscr S$, the function
   $$
     x\in  X\mapsto  \langle \xi (x),\eta (x)\rangle \in {\mathbb C}
     $$
   is continuous.

As Stefaan showed in his answer to [1],  every representation of  $C_0(X)$ splits the underlying Hilbert
space as a direct integral relative to a *measurable* field $\mathscr H$ of Hilbert spaces.

Let us now consider a separable C*-algebra $B$, and let  $$A\subseteq B$$ be a non-degenerate, closed
*-subalgebra.  Suppose moreover that $A$ is commutative, with spectrum $X$, and hence $A\simeq C_0(X)$.

Given a representation $\pi $ of $B$ on a Hilbert space $H$, one can consider the restriction of
$\pi $ to $A$ and then describe $H$ via a measurable field $\mathscr H$, as in [1].

**Question**.  Given $A$ and $B$, as above, can we always find a faithfull representation $\pi $ of $B$,
such that the field $\mathscr H$ refered to just above is *continuous*?

[1] [Direct integral decomposition relative to a given measure space](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392624/direct-integral-decomposition-relative-to-a-given-measure-space)